# How to get content truncated text from HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

red arrow - CSS truncating multiple line Text. This is correct and I want what.
green arrow - Now I wants to get text `'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. L...'`

[image]

When I use `document.querySelector(element).textContent` or `innerText` or `ref.current` in react, I always get the full content.

It is possibly to get *only* the truncated text from the page? (green arrow)

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.overflow').textContent);
console.log(document.querySelector('.overflow').innerText);
```

```css
.overflow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor natus quia temporibus! Delectus illo inventore officiis, perspiciatis provident rem sunt totam voluptatum? Deserunt dolores, voluptate. Dolor eius enim non praesentium?</div>
```

Comment: When a picture of some text is helpful, it should supplement a [mcve], not replace it.

Comment: The first duplicate would be reasonable, except it's wrapped in jQuery... I'd rather have a non-jQuery answer to use as dupe target. On the other hand, the actual "processing" is just native JS.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to present the problem briefly but specifically. Thank you for your help, the next question will be better.